# Inline CSS elements don't have whitespace

Tags: html, css

In my code I have this:

```
<p><b>Foo</b> bar</p>
```

But it renders as

**Foo**bar

How do you keep whitespace before and after inline elements? I want the following result:

```
<p><b>Foo</b> bar</p>
```

**Foo** bar

Comment: Renders fine for me... you have some other CSS that is affecting it.

Comment: It must display whitespace. Do you write HTML file directly or use some framework? Check page source code in your browser. Is there a whitespace?

Comment: It's generated by PHP, but it doesn't seem to work in a pure HTML file with the same CSS either. I can't find the problem what causes the tags to stick together.

Answer (score 3):

[You are doing it wrong.](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/4M2KH/).

Or rather you are doing something wrong, because what you have should just work.

Answer (score 1):

#### [It renders fine,](http://jsfiddle.net/wUGQH/)

The only thing to be concerned is about extrac spaces. HTML will not render **more than one** spaces.

Comment: I found the solution, Markdown puts every element in a <p> tag. Guess it's just a matter of 'white-space' to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

dude Just use nbsp so it will look like `"Foo  bar
"`

**Foo**  bar